# How to build exe file which includes cv module

Tags: python, opencv, camera, py2exe, pyinstaller

I am writing a simple security camera program.

I used that code for accessing camera:

```
import cv
camera = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
```

I tried .py file. It worked. But, when I compiled and ran exe file, I could not access camera. Program didn't react. On .py file, I could choose the camera from a window which has title named 'Video Source'.

I think that this problem about accessing authorities.

After that, I opened exe file through visual studio 2010's "debugging" feature. I got that warning:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
```

By the way, I got these outputs from the "output" tab:

```
'security_camera.exe': Loaded '[file_path(C:\Users\........)]', Binary was not built with debug information.
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\guard32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\fltLib.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5\comctl32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rsaenh.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'security_camera.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x02691fcb in security_camera.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.
The program '[8604] security_camera.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

By the way, when I open exe file(program), it closes down in 3-4 seconds.

How Can I solve it ? Thanks.

Note:
My python version : 2.7.3

I am using Windows 7 (32-bit)

Edit:

I built exe file through py2exe.

My setup.py is that:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, 'includes': 'numpy'}},
    windows = [{'script': "security_camera.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Comment: I built it with py2exe. 
My setup file is that:
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1, 'compressed': True, 'includes': 'numpy'}},
    windows = [{'script': "security_camera.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)

Comment: unrelated, but you should rather use cv2 than the deprecated cv module

Comment: But, I used codes from the Internet. I found them from the Internet. In the code from the Internet, programmer(who writed these codes) has used cv module. cv's usage and cv2's usage are different and I don't know how can I convert these codes to cv2.

Comment: just know, that this api is removed in opencv3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `py2exe`, try [`pyinstaller`](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/)

Here are some simple instructions:

1) Install pyinstaller. If you have `pip`, it's as simple as this:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

2) Create your executable:

```
pyinstaller --onefile <your python script>
```

Comment: I have already tried it. But, it didn't work.
When I opened it, I got error:
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Comment: @python_pardus Googling that error gives several results, I don't know if they are relevant for your case. But I would try to go for that path, an import error might be easier to solve than a seg fault.

Comment: Sorry, what does "seg" mean ? I'm not a native.

Comment: @python_pardus Being a native wouldn't help :) It's the short for "segmentation", [segmentation fault](https://www.google.de/search?q=segmentation+fault), Visual Studio seems to be reporting you are trying to access memory at address `0x00000000` which is not a valid address.

Comment: OK. I got it. How can I solve the seg fault ? If I use pyinstaller without error ( ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import) , I can solve it.

Comment: @python_pardus I am exactly saying, do not go for the segfault (I wouldn't know how to solve it), go for the import error. So try to fix your pyinstaller build.

Answer (score 0):

@Antonio I solved problem about pyinstaller by adding

`import numpy`

line to my script. I built exe through pyinstaller. I opened exe file. But, It did nothing. It only waited.

What should I do ?